# Configuring Flume to Collect Data into HDFS from Twitter

Tags: hadoop

Iam getting this log info continously for a whole day.

> 2016-10-12 21:32:05,696 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG -
>   org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:126)]
>   Checking file:conf/flume.conf for changes when executing the command
>   FLUME_HOME/bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/flume.conf
>   -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent

Iam getting this error now after modifying the conf file

> 2016-10-12 22:09:19,592 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [DEBUG -
>   com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource.start(TwitterSource.java:124)]
>   Setting up Twitter sample stream using consumer key  and
>   access token  2016-10-12 22:09:19,592
>   (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [ERROR -
>   org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:253)]
>   Unable to start EventDrivenSourceRunner: {
>   source:com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource{name:Twitter,state:IDLE}
>   } - Exception follows. java.lang.IllegalStateException: consumer
>   key/secret pair already set.

Comment: can you shar your flume.conf and  info logs

Comment: tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094499/getting-checking-flume-conf-for-changes-in-a-loop

Comment: I have mailed u the error

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand from what you have provide here, I think you need to add `a1.sources.r1.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource` into your conf file to define your Twitter sources, also make sure you are using your credentials for accessing twitter API.

Comment: Thanks for the help.